# Linux: Getting Mount Point Utilization from /proc?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I know I can get mount point utilization using command line tools like df and doing something like the following:

```
popen("df -h /var/log | awk '{if($1==\"tmpfs\") print $5}'","r")
```

where the fifth column is the usage percentage.

What I want to know is if there is a way to access mount point utilization from /proc/, such as /proc/mounts. I feel that getting this information from /proc/ would be a quicker and more efficient solution than using df and awk to parse out the usage. I've searched mntent.h but couldn't find anything promising there either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) syscall (it does not use `/proc/`). You probably would use it thru [statvfs(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html) Posix function.

Notice that the `/proc/` filesystem (and also `/sys/` ...) contains pseudo-files which are generated by the kernel on demand without any IO. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You could read sequentially `/proc/self/mounts` and/or `/proc/self/mountstats` and/or appropriate files under `/proc/fs/` and/or `/sys/` (such as  some files in `/proc/fs/ext4/sda1/` or even in `/sys/block/sda/sda1/` for *my* desktop computer ; it would be different on *yours* ....)

Perhaps [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) is also able to give such information, but I don't know it enough.

Comment: This is absolutely superior to using df and awk to get fs usage stats from C code. The performance boost was orders of magnitude better. Good answer.

Comment: How can I use deduce block device name where the filesystem is placed using statfs(2)?

Comment: @0x2207: I am not sure to understand your question (and in pathological cases, a block device might exist without any name, or have several names). You might consider using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), perhaps `/proc/self/mounts`

Comment: I mean I would like to deduce "mount source" for the given file path.

Comment: You might parse `/proc/self/mounts` or `/proc/self/mountstats`